# [Theory]: VHDL - For Loop possible or just a simple counter?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Lets say I have a input.

```
inputData : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)
```

At the moment I handle all 8 data bytes from inputData.
I have a fsm which processes the data.
For Example:

```
State A, State B, State C for processing inputData(7 downto 0) 
again 
State A, State B, State C for processing inputData(15 downto 8) 
.
.
.
State A, State B, State C for processing inputData(63 downto 56) 
At the end I go throw State D, E and F...
```

Now I want to make this more flexible.
To make this possible I have now two inputs:

```
inputData : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)
dataLength: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
```

Now it could be that I have only 3 Bytes of inputData that I want to handle.

For example:

```
State A, State B, State C for processing inputData(7 downto 0)
wait a little bit and then again
State A, State B, State C for processing inputData(15 downto 8)
wait a little bit and then again
State A, State B, State C for processing inputData(23 downto 16)
wait a little bit and then again
At the end I go throw State D, E and F...
```

Should or can I use the For-Statement for this or should I use a simple counter?

Is it correct when I do the following when I want to use the For-Statement?
Pseudocode:

```
process (clk)
begin
    for I in 0 ... dataLength loop
        if(I not dataLength) then
Go though State A,B,C with dataByte I
else
Go though State A,B,C with dataByte I
and then through State D, E, F and then break ... 
end if
    end loop;
end process;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "`State A, State B, State C for processing`" and "`At the end I go throw State D, E and F`". As of such, I find it difficult to understand your question.

Comment: As far as I know you can't use `for` loops to make sequential processes. So I would say you have to use a counter.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the question.
Im new to VHDL and taught that the for statement works like the for-loops in c or java...

Comment: @A.Kieffer then you're forgetting the (combinatorial) [`generate`](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/generate.html) statement, as mentioned in the answer by Renato.

Comment: What @Mansour is looking for is a way to loop as many times as needed by `datalength` between his states `A, B and C `. I don't see any mean to create the FSM with `generate` actually

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the for loop in 2 ways:

if data length is known at compilation time (e.g. generic constant) you can use the construct: `for I in 0 to datalength-1 GENERATE`

if data length can change during runtime the you need to use: `for I in 0 to datalength-1 LOOP`

Please notice that, because I used "datalength-1" you don't need the check if(I not datalength) since you will never go to actual datalength

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: A loop needs to define static bounds for synthesis. You can't have a bound based on a signal value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what do you want to achieve. I don't mean the general computation, but more what cycle timing is wished?

**Solution 1:**
Each computation requires 1 clock cycle and is equal to one FSM state. Then you would either need as many FSM states. Not a very generic approach, because changing the input width needs more fixed coded states.

The better solution is a counter that gives:
a. the index to process the input data
b. the condition to leave the current FSM state after processing all input bytes

**Solution 2:**
If all data can be process in just one clock cycle (be careful of the resulting maximum delay), then you can use a `for .. loop` statement and *unroll* all computations in one clock cycle / FSM state.